# Configure IIS to support http://localhost

Tags: iis

I am running IIS on Windows 2012 R2. For some reason, when I start IIS, http://localhost/link does not load , but http://{my machine name}/link does work.

That tells me my IIS started and listening on port 80. And able to handle 'link' as url path. But why would http://localhost/link does not load? I get a 503 error.

And when I open IIS manager, I see under 'Start Page', my 'machine name' and when I move my mouse over the machine name', it said 'http://localhost'.  But when I load 'http://localhost' in IE, I get a 503.

Can you please tell me where in the IIS configure that? Or what should I check to investigate this issue.

I find a rule like this:

> Reserved URL            : http://localhost:80/
>       User: aUser
>           Listen: Yes
>           Delegate: No
>           SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-124525095-708259637-1543119021-1467807)

Can I find out what does this rule suppose to do? before I removed it?

Comment: To which IPs is IIS bound? 0:0.0.0 ? Only its external IP? 127.1 ? ::1 ?

Comment: According to this ( http://serverfault.com/questions/148439/how-can-i-control-which-ip-address-iis7-uses ) that information is under the"Sites" folder in IIS manager

Comment: This is related to the bindings on the IIS site. Do you have a specific IP address assigned to the binding or is it set to *?

Comment: take a look inside the hosts file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc maybe there is an entry for localhost which points to something else than 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try entering in Command Prompt (cmd) the following command :

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

This will list all URLs that are reserved (disallowed) for handling by
specific programs. This list takes precedence over any other rule.

You might find some URL that relates to `localhost`, or to `127.0.0.1`,
or which will look like `http://+:80/`.

In that case, delete the rule via :

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80/
```

Comment: I find a rule based on your response. Can I find out what does that rule supposed to do? I see 'Listen : Yes', I am not sure what is it suppose to do?

Comment: The command [add urlacl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to reestablish the rule. Try delete/add in a VM if you are unsure (the  SDDL may not be identical in a VM). You can also create a system restore point as backup.

Comment: Or you could add an identical rule, only substituting "localhost" by nonsense such as "abcabcabc". Once you are sure that you can recreate this url, try and delete it. For your question about what does this url do: I don't know which program uses it.